Does "high talk" mean "serious talk" in this context?
This context comes from the book "To Kill A Mocking Bird" by Harper Lee. This is a conversation between Atticus and his daughter Jean (Scout) after she asked him why he took on as a client an Afro-American to defend in court.
"Scout, you aren’t old enough to understand some things yet, but there’s
been some high talk around town to the effect that I shouldn’t do much about
defending this man."
Does "high" in this context mean:

Serious; grave: high crimes and misdemeanors. (American Heritage® Dictionary)

expressing or feeling contempt or arrogance: high words.(Collins Dictionary)



It's informal and means 'arising from strong feelings'.

I have read the book and "high talk" most definitely refers to the first definition: serious or grave talk. Atticus explains to Scout that there has been serious talk about his decision to defend Tom Robinson around town. It does not suggest arrogance or contempt, but rather indicates that the topic is being discussed seriously by the townspeople.

This is right for southern speech.

No, because the high talk is like talking with parents or rumors. But serious talks are like talking business or talking very precisely.
